# Jekyll liquid show more posts

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I have a page where I show my posts like the following

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:3 %}
<a href="{{site.baseurl}}{{post.url}}" style="text-decoration: none; margin: 1rem;">
    <div class="newsBox">
        <div style="margin: auto;">
            <h1 style="text-align: center; color: white;">{{post.title}}</h1>
            <p style="text-align: center; color: white;">
                {{post.description}}
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center; color: #101a31; font-style: italic; font-size: 1.2rem;">
                {{post.date | date:"%d-%m-%Y"}}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

And that works fine, but I also want to show a "More" button if there are more posts that are not shown.. does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Ok so I sort of figured it out by doing this ```{% assign psize = site.posts | size %}
    {% if psize > 3 %}
    <p>more posts</p>
    {% endif %}```, but now I need to know how to show the 3 next posts..

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the users to be redirected to another page with more posts, or the posts to be displayed on the same page?

Jekyll build you website, and then makes it static, so you can't have a button have Jekyll add more content to your page after it is built.

If you want more to be shown on the page, you can work around this by looping through the posts folder, commenting it out, and the remove the commenting if the button is clicked.